# Flutter - Rebuild Widget when using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

Tags: flutter

I have an app where where I am using `BottomNaviagtionBar` where the state of the pages is preserved by using `PageView` and `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`. Using these, my pages are not getting rebuilt as I switch through them which is what I want.

However, there are cases where I need to rebuild those pages,

e.g. An hour passed by since I last opened the app. So, now when my app resumes - I wanted to rebuild some or all of those pages.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Why not save a timestamp of the last time the view was built locally on `SharedPreferences` and then compare the next time the user opens the app? If it's more than an hour, as you said, then you force the rebuild of the view with a `setState`.

Comment: For this example it can be done. That was a bad example I posted. Assuming I am on a `Page` - sitting there for 30 minutes - now, how to post a message to this widget that it should rebuild. This will also be true for where one `Widget` has stream open to a server file and wants to send data to this `Page`.